# Saving attributes as a variable in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm updating some attributes in my rails controller:

```
update_attributes(question_id: question, content: answer_and_tracking_array[0], tracking: answer_and_tracking_array[1])
```

Can I pull out the actual attributes and store in a variable, e.g.:

```
attributes = "question_id: question, content: answer_and_tracking_array[0], tracking: answer_and_tracking_array[1]"

update_attributes(attributes)
```

But this will make attributes a literal string instead of my desired values, right? What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [update_attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes) accepts a Hash parameter, you may initialize a Hash variable as follows:

```
attributes = {
  question_id: question, 
  content: answer_and_tracking_array[0], 
  tracking: answer_and_tracking_array[1]
}
```

And pass it to update_attributes.